# Non-preemptive Pthreads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

Is there a way to use pthreads without a scheduler, so context switch occurs only if a thread explicitly yields, or is blocked on a mutex/cond?  If not, is there a way to minimize the scheduling overhead, so that forced context switches will occur as rarely as possible?

The question refers to the Linux gcc/g++ implementation of POSIX threads.

Comment: Minimizing context switches and process/thread migrations is usually one of the targets of the CPU schedulers. Are you facing a specific issue?

Comment: The specific issue is that in the application that I am developing, there is a group of threads that explicitly yields, and performing any other context switches is really redundant.

Comment: And did you measure that whatever context switches are happening are detrimental to your app's throughput?

Comment: There are some that might say that sched_yield() is a redundant context switch.  If a thread is doing useful work, why would it bother to yield?  If it has no useful work to do, it should be blocked on something, waiting for more useful work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Pth (a.k.a. [GNU Portable Threads](http://www.gnu.org/s/pth/)), a non-preemptive thread library. Configuring it with `--enable-pthread` will create a plug-in replacement for `pthreads`. I just built and tested this on my Mac and it works fine for a simple pthreads program.

From the README:

> Pth is a very portable POSIX/ANSI-C based library for Unix platforms
>     which provides non-preemptive priority-based scheduling for multiple
>     threads of execution (aka `multithreading') inside event-driven
>     applications. All threads run in the same address space of the server
>     application, but each thread has its own individual program-counter,
>     run-time stack, signal mask and errno variable.
>
> The thread scheduling itself is done in a cooperative way, i.e., the
>     threads are managed by a priority- and event-based non-preemptive
>     scheduler. The intention is, that this way one can achieve better
>     portability and run-time performance than with preemptive scheduling.
>     The event facility allows threads to wait until various types of
>     events occur, including pending I/O on filedescriptors, asynchronous
>     signals, elapsed timers, pending I/O on message ports, thread and
>     process termination, and even customized callback functions.
>
> Additionally Pth provides an optional emulation API for POSIX.1c
>     threads (`Pthreads') which can be used for backward compatibility to
>     existing multithreaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a process running in normal user land, context switches will naturally happen as part of the system operation - there is always another process that needs the CPU time. Preemptive context switches between your threads are quite well optimized by the OS already and are bound to be necessary sometimes.

If you really happen to have problems with excessive context switching, you are best off tweaking the Linux scheduler first, which is off-topic here. pthread_setschedprio and pthread_setschedparam can set some hints, but are limited to setting priorities, and the interpretation of these priorities is implementation-defined, i.e. up to the Linux scheduler.